# Convert kendodatepicker format to .Net DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

The Json value of kendodatepicker that is received at .net csharp code is

"\"2013-11-18T03:38:21.843Z\""

What is the best and universal way to parse/convert this format to c# DateTime ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have it convert it to localtime, use:
`DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2013-11-18T03:38:21.843Z")`

To keep it as UTC, drop the Z off of the end:
`DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2013-11-18T03:38:21.843")`

Don't forget to dump all of those quotes and escape quotes if they really are present in the string (and not just there because of debugger output).

Answer (score -1):

From kendo dateTime to .net DateTime

```
var datepicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker");
var value = datepicker.value();
kendo.toString(value,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Try it sir.It might helps u.

Comment: This is javascript, but the OP asked for .net code to parse the json string into a `DateTime`.